# Ruby on Rails 4 endless scrolling

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll

I have a Ruby on Rails 4 application that needs endless scrolling. The problem (i think) is that it won't respond_to index.js.erb

My index action looks like this:

```
def index
  @rats = Rat.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2).order("created_at DESC ")
  @avg_reviews = []
  for singlerat in @rats
    @reviews = Review.where(rat_id: singlerat.id)
    if @reviews.blank?
      @avg_reviews << 0
    else
      @avg_reviews << @reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

If I move the respond_to above the code that gets the average star rating, it returns this error:

```
undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass
```

My index.html.erb look like:

```
<div id="rats">
  <%= render 'rats' %>
</div>
<div class="text-center"><%= will_paginate @rats, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %></div>

<script>
    $('.star-rating').raty({
      path: '/assets/',
      readOnly: true,
      score: function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
</script>
```

My _rats partial looks like:

```
  <div id="rat">
    <% @rats.each_with_index do |rat, i| %>
      <%= link_to (image_tag (rat.image (:thumb)), class: 'center-block img-responsive'), rat %>
      <div class="star-rating text-center" data-score=<%= @avg_reviews[i] %>> </div>
      <p class="text-center">Submitted by <%= rat.user.username %></p>
      <p><%= truncate(rat.description, length: 200) %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My rats.js.coffee looks like:

```
 $(window).on 'scroll', ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    @url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
    if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
      $('.pagination').remove()
      $('#rats').append('<div>')
      $('#rats div').last().load @url+' #rats', ->
          if $('.next_page.disabled').length
            $('.pagination').remove()
```

And my index.js.erb looks like:

```
$('#rats').append('<%= escape_javascript render 'rats' %>');
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript will_paginate @rats  %>');
```

The page loads the set amount of items and acts as if I haven't even tried to implement endless scrolling.

Comment: Hey Tom, please improve the formatting of your question, thanks.

Comment: If you move the respond_to block before the part which sets a value for a variable, then that variable won't be set, and will thus evaluate to nil, causing the `undefined method 'each_with_index' for nil:NilClass` error.  I can't see any reason why you would want to do that in the first place: it's a total red herring for your actual problem.

Comment: Yes thank you, that's why I moved it below.